# Spring Redis Cache

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-cache

New to Spring, have an old Spring Project, **NOT Spring Boot**
Need to implement in memory cache using Redis,
Following this guide - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-setting-ttl-value-cache

To start with, added just only bellow two dependency

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.7.5")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.7.5")
```

When I start the application after compilation, I am getting -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartUp
```

Could not find an example of **Redis Cache only for Spring** (all are for Spring Boot).

**Need to implement Redis Cache on Spring only, NOT on Spring Boot.**

Comment: Have you tried [Spring Data Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:setup) instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`?

Comment: Thank you, let me try it.
But, what about spring-boot-starter-cache, will it remain same?

Comment: As far as I understand you do not want to use Spring Boot, so do not add any Spring Boot dependencies.

Comment: If add only implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.7.5"), getting "Could not initialize class org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories"